# Get type in tagged union from tag in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a tagged union:

```js
type Circle = {type: 'circle', radius: number}
type Square = {type: 'square', size: number}
type Shapes = Circle | Square
type ShapeTypes = Shapes['type']
```

and a function that takes a `ShapeTypes` literal and returns a `Shapes`:

```js
function getShape(type: ShapeTypes): Shapes {
   // irrelevant
}
```

but all the caller of `getShape` knows about the return type is that it's a `Shapes`:

```js
const circle: Circle = getShape('circle') // error: Type 'Shapes' is not assignable to type 'Circle'
```

how can i extract the correct type? the value of `type` will always be a literal, so i feel like the compiler has enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this seems to be possible using [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#predefined-conditional-types):

```js
function getShape<T extends ShapeTypes>(type: T): Extract<Shapes, {type: T}> {}
```